# Give $N\in \mathbb{N}$ for the sequence $a_n=3+(-1)^n$ so that for every $n>N$ and $\epsilon=0.5$...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this probably very basic problem and I'm not sure how to solve it properly.

Given the sequence $a_n=3+(-1)^n$ and $\epsilon=0.5$ find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for every $n>N$ it is true that $|a_n-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n|<\epsilon$.

So basically I need to find $N$ based on the convergent sequence's definition.

My thought process is like this:

$a_n$ does not converge, it's divergent and more specifically: an oscillating sequence.

**Proof:**

In order for a $a_n$ to converge every subsequence of $a_n$ must converge to the same number.

The odd subsequence of $a_n$, $a_{2n+1}$ converges to $2$ as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}3+(-1)^{2n+1}=2$

The even subsequence of $a_n$, $a_{2n}$ converges to $4$ as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}3+(-1)^{2n}=4$

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{2n+1}\ne\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{2n}$, $a_n$ has no limit.

So I can only find $N$ for the sub sequences of $a_n$.

And that would be every every $n$, because every $a_n$ is closer to the limit (it is basically the limit) than $\epsilon=0.5$. Or do I need to find $N$ so that $|a_n-N|<\epsilon$ is true for both sub sequences??

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$ does not exist: $(a_n)=(2,4,2,4,...)$

Comment: Could you precisely state the question? You're right that $a_n$ doesn't converge, which means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ is undefined, and so the question as written is malformed. What did the question say originally?

Comment: @TheoBendit It's not in English, but I'll try my best to translate it word-to-word: Based on the definition of the limit of a sequence give $n_0(0.5)$ (more commonly noted as $N$ in English), from which every term of the sequence will be closer to a number (??? assumed it was the limit), than 0.5. Does the sequence have a limit?

Comment: Such an $n_0$ or $N$ will not exist. Is that what the question is asking you to prove? If so, then proving $a_n$ does not converge with subsequences is not quite answering the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that $N$ does not exist without proving that $a_n$ doesn't have a limit.

Comment: @Benjamin Yeah, if you prove the fact that, regardless of the number ???, there does not exist an $N$ with the given properties, then you have a proof that $a_n$ does not have a limit. Would that be a problem, if we answered both questions with one argument?

Comment: @TheoBendit How would you prove that $N$ does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the [question in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4333907/give-n-in-mathbbn-for-the-sequence-a-n-3-1n-so-that-for-every-nn-a?noredirect=1#comment9038335_4333907), let's assume, for the sake of contradiction, that some $L$ and $N$ exist such that
$$n > N \implies |a_n - L| < \frac{1}{2}$$
Fix some odd $m > N$. Then

- $a_m = 2$,
- $m + 1 > N$,
- $a_{m + 1} = 4$.

Using $n = m$, we get $|2 - L| < \frac{1}{2}$, and using $n = m + 1$, we get $|4 - L| < \frac{1}{2}$. Using triangle inequality,
$$2 = |(4 - L) - (2 - L)| \le |4- L| + |2 - L| < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1,$$
hence $2 < 1$, a contradiction. Thus, no such pair $L$ and $N$ can exist.

If the limit of $a_n$ did exist, then we would have such a pair, but since no such pair exists, the limit of $a_n$ does not exist.